# Objective-C Send arguments from terminal when cocoa app is already launching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, command-line

I'm trying to pass some arguments to an UI-based program (cocoa app) through terminal commands while the app is already in launch.
For example:

```
open appName.app -openUI                         // Shows App UI
open appName.app -forceQuit 5                    // Force quit App after 5 seconds
open appName.app -sendMsg "Hello World."         // Add "Hello World" to UNUserNotificationCenter
```

I will be very grateful if someone can guide me how to implement this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the arguments in that way, they will be send to the `open` command - which does not recognize them.

You need to put a `--args` in front of them in order to tell `open` to pass all the follwing arguments to the app launched, e.g.

`open appName.app --args -openUI`

#### Update

If the app is already running, `open` will use the running app. If you want to create a new window, you need to provide the `-n` parameter:

`open appName.app -n --args -openUI`

Comment: I used --args but it didn't work.
Here's the portion in int main:
`NSString *param1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];`
`if ([[param1 lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"-openui"]) {
NSLog("Opening UI...");
}`
Then terminal won't print "Opening UI".